# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.12.RELEASE:run (default-cli)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

... "on project Jwplusapp: An exception occurred while running. null"

Does anyone know why I cannot select "spring-boot:run" through maven without getting that error?
Ive tried renaming the database file also making sure parent versions were correct. i tried to check the pom.xml but i think i am just missing it. any help in regards to this error code would be greatly appreciated. yes i saw similar posts but they didnt seem to fix the problem for me.

**POM XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.12.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Jwplusapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Jwplusapp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.Properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Jwplus
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

**ApplicationConfig.java**

```
package com.test.Jwplusapp;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.Jwplusapp")
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("css/**", "images/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/", "classpath:/static/images/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need more information on that exception.

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand. The error code itself is all there but for more information on the exception I get kind of lost.

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.12.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project Jwplusapp: An exception occurred while running. null

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your pom.xml and it worked for me. It fails with same error only when you have same port (8080 or whatever you are using in the application) has already been occupied.

Can you please check the availability of the port on which you are trying to run.(if its occupied try running on other port or kill the same).

Also can you please paste the complete error after "null" in the stacktrace.

Updated:

make sure you have following properties in your project

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_examplele
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

And try below configuration if you are using jpa

```
@Configuration        
public class HibernateConfig {

@Bean
public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
     HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean factory = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
     factory.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
     return factory;

}
}
```

Comment: plugin:2.1.12.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project Jwplusapp: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set -> [Help 1]

Comment: Nothings on Port8080  I have nothing else running

Comment: What do you think the solution will be?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was not because of an error in my code but the solution was to  Download MySQL Installer - MySQL

Here is the link to download

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjEh8aMnbbnAhXKjVkKHSbQCSoQFjAAegQICxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdownloads%2Finstaller%2F&usg=AOvVaw2HevAKGob4r4A7Rv_R2hy5

I figured this out when checking my services and noticing that MYSQL80 service was not displayed.(Checked Services, also Task manager -> Services)

This then installed MySQL80 Service which was missing from my device, This then allowed my "spring-boot:run" to process successfully and open up my fully functioning webpage while connected to the desired localhost 3306 and fully connect to root on MYSQL workbench.